# getHostServices(); Method not found.

Tags: java, javafx, pdf-viewer

I want to open pdf files using the code below, but method getHostServices(); is not found even though i have the right imports.

```
import javafx.application.HostServices;

ClinicFiles clinicFiles = (ClinicFiles) listViewClinic.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(); 
HostServices hostServices = getHostServices();
hostServices.showDocument(clinicFiles.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: More code, please!

Comment: this is all i have to complete the task. just getHostServices(); is warning: cannot find symbol. @EleazarEnrique

Comment: You need to provide context. The `getHostServices()` method is defined in the `Application` class. Are you calling this in an `Application` subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, your class is not extending from `javafx.application.Application:`

**For example:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.HostServices;

public class App extends Application {
    public void method(String[] args) {
        ClinicFiles clinicFiles = (ClinicFiles) listViewClinic.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        HostServices hostServices = getHostServices();
        hostServices.showDocument(clinicFiles.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i needed an instance of application.xD

Comment: Your welcome, can you mark the answer with an upvote?